# Apple ID Misfortune

Tags: iphone, icloud, email, apple-id

My friend recently gave me an old iPhone was a little banged up. I took the liberty of fixing it up. The issue now is that it has her brothers AppleID  on it. We have spent a week trying different solutions and spent the last couple of days talking to apple support.

The issue is he can’t input his password because the account is blocked (we assume cause its been inactive for so long) this would not be an issue because we actually know the password. our next issues come at the security questions and email address. The questions are an issue because he doesn't remember his answer or how exactly he spelled certain answers. the issue of sending an email is that he misspelled his email (by forgetting to add a .za at the end) so the reset email does not reach the right email address.

Comment: Are you trying to unlocked the phone after resetting it? Or are you just trying to remove the brothers Apple ID from the phone. Is it a possibility to erase the phone?

Comment: The phone has already been reset and  we are not trying to unlock it after reset

Comment: Where are you trying to enter in the password and for what reason? What does it say on the screen?

Comment: When i enter the password it says the account is blocked

Comment: If the account is blocked(or locked) it can be unlocked by resetting the password. If you are entering the password after resetting the phone to activate it(remove the Find My iPhone lock) you can bring the phone to an Apple store. Once they confirm your the owner of the phone they’ll unlock it for you.

Comment: The proof of purchase is nowhere to be found. so what other ways can i verify ownership? an affidavit from the police??

Comment: I’m not sure what an affidavit is... but if it’s just saying you own the phone and it’s from the police, it might work but I’m not sure. What also might work would be bringing the registered owner with you to the Apple store, make sure they have an form of government issued ID.

Comment: I just looked up what an affidavit is, it could possibly work. It just depends on apples policy for unlocking devices which I do not completely know.

Comment: I would recommend if you get an affidavit you should check with Apple ahead of time to see if they would accept one, as they can cost money and take some time to get one.

Comment: Would we not need a proof of purchase even if the owner is present at the apple store?

Comment: If Apple can verify that he is the owner you will not need proof of purchase, though having proof of purchase could help

Comment: How do they verify this? i mean if they try to verify by using security questions again ill probably go mad

Comment: They most likely have a database with the different purchases and who purchased the device, but I’m not sure

Comment: Do you have full control of the AppleID by signing in with a web browser? Let’s edit this down to be either about the Apple ID or about the phone once you have the account under control.  Then a follow on question can address the phone if needed.

Comment: no access to the account at all, the phone is in perfect condition

Comment: It has been a while since I last tried to sign in with an invalid primary email address on an Apple ID. What does the first screen look like after you put in the password? Make sure you're using an up-to-date browser.